# axios.get not returning JSON

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm learning the Vue.js framwork at the moment. More specific, Using Axios to Consume APIs.

I have this code:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      info: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
      .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
      //.get('http://calapi.inadiutorium.cz/api/v0/en/calendars/general-en.json')
      .then(response => (this.info = response))
  }
})
```

The `axios.get('https://api.coindesk.com...` line is working correctly. Unfortunately, the second (commented) line is not.

Is there someone who can tell me why there's no response with the commented line?

Code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zJdvzW

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codepen uses `https` but you are trying to access resource on a website that uses `http`, as you can see in console:

> spread.js:25 Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OojyYR' was loaded over HTTPS, but
>   requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   'http://calapi.inadiutorium.cz/api/v0/en/calendars/general-en.json'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

If you use jsfiddle instead of codepen it will work:
http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/335825/

Also, your requested resource is inside of `response.data`

Answer (score 1):

The response data can be retrieved from `response.data`.

`api.coindesk.com` doesn't have a CORS issue because it already includes `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header.

change your code to:

```
axios.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
.then(response => (this.info = response.data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like http://calapi.inadiutorium.cz/api/v0/en/calendars/general-en.json doesn't support CORS.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the cors. You can install Google Chrome plugin called CORS and enable it. This will allow your axios call to work.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So if the end-user doesn't have the CORS plugin, it will not work? How would you get results from this API? What's the most common way to consume and display data from an API?

Comment: It will work. You are running your app from localhost and that is why you cannot access service that is CORS protected. When you put your app online there will be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the network request being made you see it fails due to a blocked mixed-content flag
[image: screenshot of network request]

A little digging suggest this may be due to the fact that the call is via http rather than https which unfortunately can only be fixed by the creator of the API. As a result the browser is failing to make the request as it's seeing the response as insecure. Read more [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content).

This doesn't really answer the question unfortunately, if the request was made from a backend it may not be so sensitive to the mixed-content but within the browser you may struggle to get results from this API. (For instance calling from postman the api response is passed with no issue)